# Using Jquery progress bar associated at action in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, progress-bar

I'm working with MVC 3 in C# in my actual project and have a doubt.
I need to insert a progress bar in all my actions that require a greater processing. 
And when I start the process, the progress bar must load according to my action.
I want working with UI Jquery tools, because it's a generic tool and easy to implement.
How do i implement this?

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to implement the progress bar in the action in MVC.
I managed to develop the progress bar through the link (http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label)
But I'd like to load the progress bar according the execution of my action.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find solution of your problem? I mean tutorial or good code to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a progress bar for longer processing actions, then you need to call them using ajax.  Then you can use a success callback to display data or do whatever you actually need after the process is done.